# Longest land path on Afro-Eurasia

Tags: geography, terminology

Regarding [Afro-Eurasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afro-Eurasia) as single continent, I tried to draw longest geodesic line within it and got

[image]

[image]

which is 16628 km (10 332 miles) length.

Looks like this line is rather stable and lasts from [Navarin cape](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD_(%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81)) in Russia to Quoin point in SAR.

Is this known feature is this really longest and what is it's name?

Comment: Since your path crosses a sea, are you just looking for the two points in Europe/Africa/Asia that are furthest apart? Or are seas considered "land" in your definition?

Comment: (also crosses into Arctic Ocean it looks like?)

Comment: Note that I believe the inspiration for this post may be a similar posting around the Internet about North America [here](http://ow.ly/fgri30kLnq9)

Comment: @BarryCarter the only assumption I made it that Suez Canal doesn't split Afro-Eurasia, other things comply definition of "diameter" of random shape: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter#Generalizations

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Arctic ocean is Ok, I am just finding two farest points of Afro-Eurasia.

Comment: Did you find these points by creating a convex hull or just by trial and error?